# Receiving H265 stream with VLC from GStreamer delay

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, delay, vlc

I am using a python code to generate a gstreamer pipeline which would stream h265 video over udp and an SDP file opened by VLC on the receiver side.

the gstreamer pipeline looks like this:

```py
self.add_element_and_link("appsrc", "source") # Add source
self.pipeline.get_by_name("source").set_property("max-latency", 0)
self.pipeline.get_by_name("source").set_property("do-timestamp", "true")
self.add_element_and_link("capsfilter", "capsfilter", link_to="source") # Create capsfilter
self.pipeline.get_by_name('capsfilter').set_property('caps', Gst.Caps.from_string(f'video/x-raw,format=(string)BGR,width=640,height=480,framerate={int(self.fps)}/1'))
self.add_element_and_link("videoconvert", "videoconvert1", link_to="capsfilter") # Create videoconvert

self.add_element_and_link("capsfilter", "capsfilter2", link_to="videoconvert1") # Create capsfilter2
self.pipeline.get_by_name('capsfilter2').set_property('caps', Gst.Caps.from_string(f'video/x-raw,format=(string)I420,width=640,height=480,framerate={int(self.fps)}/1'))
self.add_element_and_link("queue", "queue", link_to="capsfilter2") # Create queue
self.add_element_and_link("x265enc", "x265enc", link_to="queue") # Create x265enc
self.pipeline.get_by_name("x265enc").set_property('tune', 'zerolatency') # x265enc tune=zerolatency to ensure less delay
self.add_element_and_link("capsfilter", "capsfilter3", link_to="x265enc") # Create capsfilter3
self.pipeline.get_by_name('capsfilter3').set_property('caps', Gst.Caps.from_string('video/x-h265, stream-format=byte-stream'))
self.add_element_and_link("rtph265pay", "rtph265pay", link_to="capsfilter3") # Create rtph265pay
self.pipeline.get_by_name("rtph265pay").set_property('config-interval', 1) # Send VPS, SPS, PPS in order to tell receiver to get the frames even if it started after sender
self.add_element_and_link("udpsink", "udpsink", link_to="rtph265pay") # Create udpsink
self.logger.info(f"udpsink set to: {self.host}:{self.port}")
self.pipeline.get_by_name("udpsink").set_property('host', self.host)
self.pipeline.get_by_name("udpsink").set_property('port', self.port)
```

The SDP file looks like this:

```
v=0
m=video 1234 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H265/90000
```

When running the stream with VLC with the SDP file, it would show only the first frame (the frame depends on key-int-max).
If restarting the stream it would start playing but with a big delay.

when using videotestsrc instead of appsrc the stream won't freeze on the first frame and the delay is much smaller.

Does anyone have an idea why could this happen?

I have tried using different video sources, different ports, modifying the SDP file, adding do-timestamp=true to appsrc.